# Comments for my first work?

Tags: video-games, sound-design, portfolio

I find this site very usefull for my work and i decided i should submit my first work for critisism and opinions.

My first work is this little game we developed for our blog (in greek language though, but the game is in english). And i would like your comments and advises on the sound part! You can find the game here http://www.tsimpountiii.gr/free-games/ its made in Flash and i used a Sony PCM-50D, a cheap shotgun mic from Thomann and Logic!

Feel free to critisize cause i respect your opinions!

Thank you all in regard.

Nikos Chatzigeorgiadis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Nikos -

Great job! The sounds were clean and tight, no problem cutting through the music track. Very funny (although kinda disturbing!) and entertaining - I actually ended up playing quite a few rounds. Amazing what can be acheived with econo gear these days, yes?

Comment: I would like to hear what you find disturbing and in what way Jay? (have to hear all opinions right?) and yes i indeed am quite happy that i can do this kind of work with such a low budget compared to 5 years before!

Comment: Oh nothing really, just smashing the poor tiki dudes to bits with a bloody bone and getting much amusement out of it!

Comment: haha as my graphic designer pointed out! "its not really blood!, its chocolate!!!"

Answer (score 3):

On the menus, the music loops its theme for about 6 or 8 times.  On the loop back, there is a pop and and brief silence before the loop starts again.  On the "upgrade menu" there is no pop, but still the silence.  Probably just need to fade out briefly on the start/end of the music tracks.

I would also have liked to have a more satisfying sound for the "hits".  Something with a crack or a squish.  Something this repetitive needs to have audio variety beyond the "ooofs" and screams.

On the upgrade screen, there is the same "cucoo clock" sound whether you're able to buy an upgrade or not.  It would be nice to get a negative buzzer sound or something similar if you don't have enough cash, and the positive sound when you make a purchase.

Other than that, sounds good, game play is very simple and fun.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I agree, very nice sound scape.

The music was Perfect, and the mix was nice and clean.

I would have liked to hear less pitch variation on the bad guy deaths, but more versions of them so they don't become too repetitive.  i preferred the lower pitch bad guys.  It matched the character more.

I would also like to hear a beefier thud when they get squashed.

My $0.02

Answer (score 0):

thank you all guys for the advises, all coming into the next Update of the game. I am very happy to announce that the next update is currently developed for a very big greek website, that they want to embedd it in their webpage for contests so everything is going really well!

Thank you all again.

Comment: it's awesome. Congratz!